# Could not find andengine.apk?

Tags: reference, apk, andengine

I tried copying some code from one project to another, but on the second project, when I run it, I get the errors:

```
    [2012-07-09 17:06:34 - AndEngine] Could not find AndEngine.apk!
[2012-07-09 17:06:34 - AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension] Could not find AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.apk!
```

And:
[image: Errors]

I've read through the numerous suggested solutions and nothing seems to work. So far I have tried deleting the r.java, deleting and reimporting the project, cleaning, refreshing, moving AndEngine's libs folder to the current project, making sure "is library" is unchecked, running  2.2, and using Java 1.6.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add andengine to the build path of your project and launch the project.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not very sure of the solution, but here are some suggestions:

Under your library section, there are 2 `X`s, which means your project refers to 2 other library projects but cannot find them properly in the path. Try to `Add` the correct AndEngine or PhysicsBox2D library project path and `remove` the wrong ones. You will then see a `tick` rather than an `X`.

Besides that, it is also possible that your AndEngine or PhysicsBox2D library project is not compiling properly (due to errors or wrong settings). If that is the case, you need to resolve those errors.

---

Edit 1:
I think the second case I mentioned will not happen:
[image]
The picture indicates that even the AndEngine project contains error, the Reference status will still show a `tick`.

Thus, it is more likely that the path is broken. Since you already added the AndEngine to your current workspace, you might want to try to re-add your Reference Library.

Comment: Yes I know they are supposed to be green check marks and not red x's. That's the problem. The path is correct and the files exist in those paths. What wrong settings?

Comment: Have you checked out the AndEngine project form the repository or are you using an outdated .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but in case of third party libs if you get some R.JAVA problem then this problem is related to build path.

So remove all third party jar files again paste it into the root directory and libs of your project. Clean your project, run it. Hope problem will be resolved.